# Rid me of my start and finish, and I just am

Tags: riddle, word

> Without me, I am visited.
> With me, I am played.
> But rid me of my start and finish, and I just am.
>
> What/who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My shot:

> game

Without me, I am visited.

> <strike>still thinking at this one. Somehow `game` without `me` (`ga`) might mean something?????</strike>
>  With the help of my friends BeastlyGerbil and El-Guest....
>  game without me is GA which can be the country iso2 code of Gabon or the code for the state of Georgia USA. Both can be visited. (just make sure you keep the 2 meters distance from everyone while doing so)
>  (thank you both)

With me, I am played.

> the word `game` contains `me` at the end. And a game is played.

But rid me of my start and finish, and I just am.

> remove the first and last letters in `game` and you end up with `am`.

Comment: Just beat me to it! I'm also least sure on the first point but 'GA' is the country code of Gabon which you can visit?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil. oooohhh (insert revelation face here)Then maybe you should write the answer as it looks better than mine.

Comment: oh no you got pretty much all of it first! I'm not even sure that is the correct reasoning for the clue anyway :)

Comment: It’s also the state abbreviation for Georgia, USA

Comment: I was going for GA as in Georgia, USA, nice job :)

Comment: yeah. it was kind of hard for me that one. I don't think I can name the codes for all the counties in my country, let alone USA. :)